# How to fill a text box in Microsoft Word with data from a MS Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, textbox, autofill

Hello I am having trouble with trying to auto fill a word document with data that is calculated from my MS Access form.
I have been following along with this Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k176qcg-YCo and when I run the code it opens word but it gets stuck in a loop, I believe. The function is called when the button is clicked, the code is provided below. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
Function fillwordform()
Dim appword As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim Path As String

On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear

Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set appword = New Word.Application
appword.Visible = True
End If
Path = "C:\Users\Jay\Documents\Monthly Update.docx"
Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(Path, , True)
With doc
    .FormFields("ItmRec").Result = Me.NVCItmRcv

appword.Visible = True
appword.Activate
End With

Set doc = Nothing
Set appword = Nothing

End Function
```

The "ItmRec" is the name of the text box im trying to fill in Word and the "Me.NVCItmRcv" is the name of the box that I want to pull the number from and put in the text box. If you need anymore details or anything please let me know! Again highly appreciate any help!

Comment: The big question in Word always is: What *kind* of "text box". There are (at least) four different possibilities, and all need to be addressed differently in the object model. First thing you need to do is remove `On Error Resume Next` as that's hiding error messages which might give you a clue what the problem is. Probably, you'll then get an error on the line with `.FormFields`. Then you need to describe HOW the textbox was created in the Word document.

Comment: @Cindy Meister The text box was created under the developer tab, underneath legacy forms. the text box field. Then I double clicked and changed the name just like in the video. Should I try to use Merge fields for it?

Comment: No, don't use merge fields if you want to use VBA. Those are for end-users to create letters from a data base. What happens when you remove On Error Resume Next, as I advised?

Comment: @CindyMeister Oh my goodness. Nevermind I figured out that the document was a .doc not a .docx. And then it worked! Thank you so much for your help! I really really appreciate it!!

Comment: Glad you tracked it down :-) You still need to clean up that error stuff, though...  After `End If` insert a line: `On Error GoTo 0` which will turn error handling back on after the Word.Application is initiated (either with a running instance or with a new instance).